# Meteor account-ui: How do I create a user with email and password then ask them to complete a profile once logged in?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've installed the account-ui package for Meteor, that's working fine.  I've created a schema that I use to create a form using the autoform package and that is also working fine.

I ran "meteor reset" to clear the database.  I then went through the process of creating a user.  I entered an email address and a password then clicked "Create" and I got an error saying that a required field was missing.  This field appears on my schema so I guess its understandable that it displays.

I'm happy that the default form just asks for an email address and password.

My question is this, how do I allow the user to sign up with just an email address and password and then once logged in complete the profile that is defined in my schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new schema which is completely separate to the user and user profile.  The new schema references the Meteor.userId() so the data saved to this schema is tied to the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this method helps
1. User inputs email and password
2. If there's a activation email it is sent ( included with the activation email is a link to complete thier profile)
3. Upon signing in the first time they are redirected to thier profile page where theyay complete thier profile if wished

```
                   <template name="SignUp">

                  <form action="/sign-up" id="signUpForm"                method="post">
                  <input id="signUpEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" >
                  <input id="signUpPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                  <input id="signUpPasswordConfirm"     name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password">
                 <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Join Meteorites!">
                 </form>
                 <!-- end #sign-up-form -->

                 </template>
```

That should be a bit similar to what you have, you need to be able to recongnizes first logins attempts :) afterword you make a event upon first login being true, this event is a simple link to a profile page :) 
I'm extremely sorry if this doesn't help :(

Hope This Helps :) Good Luck :)

Comment: Hi, that's ideally the approach I'd like to take.  I just want to allow the user to create an account with just an email address and password.  My schema is preventing that, that's the problem I want to solve at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your code.  I'm using the accounts-ui package and that is working fine.  The problem is with my schema, "Firstname is required" is an error I'm seeing when trying to create an account.  It is a required field on the profile form.  So I need to be able to use this schema but its causing problems when trying to create an account.  That's the issue I'm trying to get around.  I'll maybe look to using a different login system in the future, for now I just want to get something working :)

Comment: No problem, thank you for your replies though.  I managed to get it sorted :)